# Category page doesn't use category.php, instead it redirects to homepage

Tags: categories, multisite, frontpage

I am currently modifying a theme. This theme doesn't had a category.php I needed a custom category page. So, I made one. It works on my local server, but when I uploaded it to a real server, this page doesn't work. It always redirect to frontpage. It has a front-page.php and other pages include
archive.php,
index.php,
Some custom page template,
single page templates,
taxonomy-custom_cat.php etc.

I mean everything is pretty normal. Everything else works fine, but on the main server category doesn't work anyway. Isn't it violating template hierarchy?

By the way, the main server is wordpress multisite. I had to enable the theme in network admin and then use it in the current site. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I found out something interesting. It redirects to frontpage or uses 404 page in the following condition
No. not all 404 urls redirect to the front page. I am giving you a general idea

```
www.example.com/category/category-name -> redirects to front page
www.example.com/category/xxxxx         -> redirects to front page
www.example.com/xxxxx                  -> redirects to front page
www.example.com/xxxx/xxxx              -> goes to 404 page
```

*xxxx means garbage url

It actually use 404 page, but not all the cases and by the way I'm using wpmudev

Comment: this happened to me once... just a small tip / test is to (first make sure you uploaded category.php) activate a different theme for a second and reactivate your theme again...

Comment: category.php is uploaded. Tried reactivating, didn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the content of the `category.php` file here (or on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com)) for us to debug? Thanks

Comment: Also, check if `NOBLOGREDIRECT` is defined in `wp-config.php`

Comment: NOBLOGDIRECT is not defined.

Comment: i bet you have tried this but... update permalinks structure pls

Comment: Anything weird in your .htaccess?  Also, triple check that you've uploaded the category.php to the right theme's folder. I have totally made errors in FTP before. What about sub-sites that have the same name as the category? Or pages with the same slug?

Comment: Does this behaviour happen on a fresh install with only the theme activated and no other plugins installed?

Comment: @TomjNowell It was a long time ago. That server was for testing purpose too. When I uploaded the theme to the original website, it worked without any problem. I don't have access to that server anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your category.php file has no errors first.

Go to Settings -> Permalinks and save it again to rebuild your permalink structure just in case.

Comment: There is no error in the category.php  As I have told before it works in my local server. I figured it is a server issue. Maybe the wordpress multisite is broken or something like that. But it's still weird.

Comment: Did you check with the permalinks?

Comment: Yes. I did, but didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your **category.php** is not uploaded to the proper folder while you upload to your server. 
Once it happened to one of my friend.

confirm that your files arranged something like this.

- **www.yourdomain.com/blog/wp-content/themes/yourblogtheme**
  inside this.
- index.php
- category.php
- date.php
- archive.php
- author.php
- style.css

or 
 - **yourblogrootfolder/wp-content/themes/yourblogtheme**
inside this.

- index.php
- category.php
- date.php
- archive.php
- author.php
- style.css

Comment: @Rifaz It was in proper order. Well, you can consider this issue resolved.

Comment: If his category.php didnt exist it would use archive.php, and if that didnt exist it would fallback to index.php. He could not have activated or viewed the theme without an index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the file permissions. Many hosts require that the permissions be 644 for PHP files. In particular suPHP will usually block execution of files that even have 664 permissions. New files uploaded via FTP may not always get umasked properly depending on the FTP client and server setup.